# How do I use environment variables in Awk

Tags: awk

I've got the following `AWK` script I'm using to update `settings.py`.
I utilising during Docker install and I'm trying to pass ENV variables.

**ENV variables to pass:**

```
DB_USER,
DB_PASS,
DB_NAME
```

The code below

```
awk 'function pr(sp, k, v){    # prints key-value pair with indentation
         printf "%s\047%s\047: \047%s\047,\n",sp,k,v; 
     }
     /sqlite/{ sub(/sqlite[0-9]*/,"mysql",$0) }
     /NAME/{ sp=substr($0,1,index($0,"\047")-1); 
             print sp$1" \047$DB_NAME\047"; 
             pr(sp,"USER","$DB_USER"); pr(sp,"PASSWORD","$DB_PASS"); 
             pr(sp,"HOST","localhost"); pr(sp,"PORT",""); next 
     }1'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `ENVIRON` variable in `GNU Awk`,

From the [GNU Awk `man` page](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html),

> `ENVIRON`
>
> An associative array containing the values of the environment. The array indices are the environment variable names; the elements are the values of the particular environment variables. For example, `ENVIRON["HOME"]` might be `"/home/arnold"`. Changing this array does not affect the environment passed on to any programs that `awk` may spawn via redirection or the `system()` function. (In a future version of `gawk`, it may do so.)

Using the above array to reference your environment variables, just do this in the `BEGIN` clause to load all the variables and use it later

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    db_user = ENVIRON["DB_USER"]
    db_pass = ENVIRON["DB_PASS"]
    db_name = ENVIRON["DB_NAME"]
 }'
```

Use the variables `db_user`, `db_pass` and `db_name` in the body of the `Awk` as you wish. By importing the environment variables in `BEGIN`, you don't have to import them once for each line in the input file.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two more ways, aside from `ENVIRON`, to get shell variables into awk programs, according to [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Using-Shell-Variables). This is especially useful when using local shell variables as `ENVIRON` works only for exported or environment variables.

There is a gotcha when trying to use variables as patterns so I will use them as patterns in our examples.

So lets say we want to get the current user's home directory from `/etc/passwd`, the separator is `:` so we need to tell awk about that by using the `-F` argument.

Without using variables we would write the simple program like this:

```bash
$ awk -F: '$1~/nickl/ {print $6}' /etc/passwd
/home/nickl
```

But instead we want to use the environment variable `$USER`.

##### Method 1. using shell string quote substitution

We can separate the awk program string by supplying both single and double quoted strings **without spaces in between**, the latter will of course allow for variable substitution where as the former ignores the `$` used by awk to denote field numbers.

```bash
$ awk -F: '$1~'"/$USER/ "'{print $6}' /etc/passwd
/home/nickl
```

##### Method 2. using command line variables

The previous method could get confusing and land you into trouble trying to keep track of separated strings, especially with more complex programs, so instead we can use [command line variable assignment](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Assignment-Options) with the `-v` option.

```bash
$ awk -F: -v var=$USER '$1~var {print $6}' /etc/passwd
/home/nickl
```

Note: You would probably want to put the variable into quotes `"$USER"` if there is any chance that it might contain spaces.

##### Method 3. using the built-in variable

As per the accepted answer, the third option is to use the [built-in variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Auto_002dset) `ENVIRON`. You may have noticed from the previous method that we are not using regexp constant, by excluding the slashes `//` from the pattern. The gotcha is when using awk variables in patterns we use [dynamic regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps) instead, without the slashes.

```bash
$ awk -F: '$1~ENVIRON["USER"] {print $6}' /etc/passwd
/home/nickl
```

EDIT: As pointed out by @RAREKpopManifesto, if directly declared we can pass local variables to be accessible by `ENVIRON`, even without changing an exported variable.

```bash
$ LOCAL_USER="rarek"
$ USER="$LOCAL_USER" awk -F: '$1~ENVIRON["USER"] {print $6}' /etc/passwd
/home/rarek
$ echo $USER
nickl
```

nJoy!

Comment: explicit export isn't needed if directly declared : `TEST_VAR1=''; TEST_VAR1='7359' mawk 'BEGIN { print ENVIRON["TEST_VAR1"] }'   
7359`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto well spotted, still `ENVIRON` does not work with local variables so the other options are still useful, do you agree?

Comment: : very much agreed. the edge case i mentioned are just that - edge cases.