# BASH - Replace text in 'ini' file using variables

Tags: bash, sed

I'm expecting this to be an easy one for someone (alas not me!).

Using a bash script, I want to replace a value in a config file '/etc/app/app.cfg' (ini style), using variables for both search and replace.

The Value Name and Value I wish to update (note the space either side of the equals:

`LOGDIR = /etc/app/logs`

I have defined the following in the bash script:

```
# Get existing LogDir value 
CURRENT_LOGDIR=$(grep 'LogDir =' /pathtofile | sed 's/LogDir *= *//g')

# Set New LogDir
LOGDIR=/mnt/eft/fs1/logs

# Update LogDir if different
if [[ -d $(echo $CURRENT_LOGDIR) != $LOGDIR ]] ; then
  # Update LogDir value:
  **bash command - I need help with !**
fi
```

I have tried many combinations with sed, to no avail, hence asking this question.

Things I've tried:

```
echo "LogDir = $LOGDIR" | sed '#s/$CURRENT_DIR/$LOGDIR/#g' /etc/app/app.cfg
sed -i '/#/!s/\(LogDir[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*\)\(.*\)/\1$LOGDIR#/g' /etc/app/app.cfg
sed -i 's/LogDir[[:space:]]=.*/LogDir = {LOGDIR}/' /etc/app/app.cfg
sed -i "s/^LogDir[[:space:]]*=.*/LogDir=$LOGDIR/}" /etc/app/app.cfg
sed -i '/#/!s/\(LogDir[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*\)\(.*\)/\1"$LOGDIR"/' /etc/app/app.cfg
```

**Desired output:**

Update LogDir value in /etc/app/app.cfg

For example:

`LogDir = /mnt/eft/fs1/logs`

Comment: (If you remove the invalid `-d` in `[[ -d ... ]]`, to make it syntactically correct) [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds several problems with the code.

Comment: It the variable name in the configuration file always starts in column 1 and has a space after it, I would consider an `awk` solution.

Answer (score 1):

What is that `}` doing on the end? Looks like a typo.

```
sed "s/^LogDir[[:space:]]*=.*/LogDir=$LOGDIR/" /etc/app/app.cfg
```

And [sed edit file in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-file-in-place)

Comment: Yep, that was a typo!

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ LOGDIR=/mnt/eft/fs1/logs
$ sed -i.bak "s|\([^=]*=[[:space:]]\).*|\1$LOGDIR|" /etc/app/app.cfg
$ cat /etc/app/app.cfg
LOGDIR = /mnt/eft/fs1/logs
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
awk '$1 == "LogDir" {print "LogDir = /mnt/eft/fs1/logs"; next} {print}' old_configuration_file >new_configuration_file
```

The first awk clause replaces the old *LogDir* entry by the new one, and the second clause passes the other lines through unchanged.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work with the LOGDIR variable.  Probably just a quote/escape issue:   
`awk '$1 == "LogDir" {print "LogDir = $LOGDIR"; next} {print}' old_configuration_file >new_configuration_file`

Comment: This would indeed not expand `$LOGDIR`, because it is between single quotes; but you don't need the **shell** to expand it. You can also either turn the shell variable into an **awk** variable (see the `-v` option in the _awk man page_), or instead make `LOGDIR` an **environment** variable and [access it from within awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171193/how-do-i-use-environment-variables-in-awk#46171338) via the predefined `ENVIRON` array - it's a matter of taste, what you find easier to read afterwards.